# Using jQuery to change hover colour (from array)?

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, hover

I was wondering if it were possible to use jQuery to change the colour of a link when hovered, getting the colour randomly from an array? I have the following but not sure how to grab the random colour.. This might be SUPER easy but I can't seem to work it out..

```
var colors = Array("#fb2900", "#ff7800", "#fff43b", "#8dfa30", "#01c86a", "#00d7b2", "#0092e3", "#002f7e", "#390e73");
$("ul.menu li a").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("color","#f0f"); //random colour would be going here
}, function() {
  $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like:

```
var colors = Array("#fb2900", "#ff7800", "#fff43b", "#8dfa30", "#01c86a", "#00d7b2", "#0092e3", "#002f7e", "#390e73"), idx;
$("ul.menu li a").hover(function(){
  idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // Pick random index
  $(this).css("color", colors[idx]);
}, function() {
  $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Math.random() and use that value to fetch an array index.you might also have to make sure that u don't access an array out of bound .

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$(this).css("color",colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
```

Also make sure your js is in a $(document).ready();

Answer (score 1):

```
var colors = ["#fb2900", "#ff7800", "#fff43b", "#8dfa30", "#01c86a", "#00d7b2", "#0092e3", "#002f7e", "#390e73"];
$("ul.menu li a").hover(function(){
  var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  $(this).css("color",color); //random colour would be going here
}, function() {
  $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
});
```

Comment: Looks like we had very similar thought patterns on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Math Javascript Object

```
var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
var random_color = Array[random_number]
$(this).css("color","random_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Range Random number function ~

```
function GetRangeRandom(min, max)
{
    return (Math.floor((max-min-1)*Math.random()) + min);
}
```